# Display new value based on selected Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I want to display the email for the selected person when selected. This is what I've got so far:

html.erb

```
<%= select_tag "", options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, :id, :name), :id =>"test" %>
```

js.coffee

```
jQuery ->

$('select#test').change ->
   $.get '/update_email/',{ id: $('option:selected', this). val() }
```

controller

```
def update_email
    @selected_person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @email = @selected_person.email
end
```

How can I display the @email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option: Create a JS view file:

views/people/update_email.js.erb

```
<%= @email %>
```

Second option: Return text value from controller:

controllers/people_controller.rb

```
def update_email
  @selected_person = Person.find(params[:id])
  @email = @selected_person.email
  render :text => @email
end
```